# Criar campo apenas no DataSet com valor padrão

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dataset, tclientdataset, embarcadero

Como crio um campo no `ClientDataSet` que não está no Banco de Dados e deixo ele com um valor padrão?

Preciso de um campo como `FLAG_EXEMPLO` padrão 'S' só que não posso criar o mesmo no banco. Precisa estar só no `DataSet`.

Já tentei usar `Calculate` e `InternalCalc` com `AutoGenerateValue` e `Default Expression`, mas nada parece funcionar. Não sei se talvez não fiz da forma correta.

Comment: Pode postar o seu código para termos uma ideia?

Comment: Cria o campo no ClientDataSet como ftString, tamanho 1, logo após dar um CreateDataSet, atribui o valor padrão para o campo como 'S' e não precisa mais alterar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer na própria SQL:

```
SELECT 'S' AS FLAG_EXEMPLO, CAMPO1, CAMPO2 FROM TABELA;
```

Comment: Depois tem é de ir ao dataset marcar o campo como editavel, senao ele marca-o como ReadOnly com esse sql. Depois se tentar alterar o valor no codigo vai dar erro :)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar campos no `ClientDataset` em runtime, depois você vai nas propriedades desse campo e informa que esse campo não vai para o banco, ou seja, quando o `ClientDataset` gera os comandos de `insert` e `update`, esse campo não é gerado no SQL.